# problem with helmet middleware in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, helmet.js

I'm working on a full stack MERN application, in the API i decided not to keep the images in the folder and uploaded them on cloudinary. i also use Graph instagram api to ge the most recent instagram images from my profile. To sum it up i use two external resource to get the images and load them on my front end but whenever i use the helmet middleware it prevents me from getting those image urls and it throws these two errors -

> Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at https://scontent.cdninstagram.com////

> Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at https://res.cloudinary.com ///

what should i do?

i tried to enable those two urls to not be blocked in the helmet itself

Comment: Agree with the comment above as it's really difficult to say what went wrong in your case. Please consider making mini viable example that recreates this issue and send us link for the repo.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) inside your question. [Not on an external website/repo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. What's the value of the `Content-Security-Policy` header in your app? Is the `img-src` directive set as you expect? Are you trying to load these with the `<img>` tag or something similar, or is it possible that you're not loading things the right way?

Comment: app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
        scriptSrc: [
          "'self'",
          "'unsafe-inline'",
          "https://res.cloudinary.com",
          "data:",
        ],
        imgSrc: [
          "'self'",
          "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com",
          "https://res.cloudinary.com",
          "data:",
        ],
      },
    },
  })
);  this is my helmet (which works this way but idk how safe is it). Yes i'm using the <img/> tag